# What is the characters for qilou, the sidewalks in Taiwan?

Tags: traditional-characters

In Taiwan, there are covered sidewalks called “qilou”. What are the characters for that, and is there a translation in English?

Answer (score 3):

wouldn't it be "騎樓"?

there's wiki page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tong_lau